# Text is leaking out from the container when zoom in or stretch it from side

Tags: html, css

My problem is that the text content is overflowing the box or container - what is the issue here ?

I heard about `max-width` and `max-height` but can't make it work.

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Product Landing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="product landing.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main class="main-container">
        <nav class="navbar-container">
            <img src="logo.svg" class="logo-img">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="select-items"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li class="select-items"><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="select-items"><a href="#">Pricing Table</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section class="features">
            <h1>The Benefits</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                 Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid</p>
            <ul class="boxs">
                <li>
                    <h2>GPS Tracking</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Heartbeat Analysis</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Security first</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Innovative idea</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Save your bills</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Proven technology</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="testimonials"></section>
        <section class="pricing"></section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.main-container {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.logo-img {
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


.navbar > :nth-child(3){
    color: aquamarine;
    background-color: cornflowerblue; 
    border : 2px solid cornflowerblue;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.navbar > li > a {
    color: blanchedalmond;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

.navbar > li > a:hover {
    color: crimson;
}

.features {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;

}

.boxs {
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 100px;
}

.testimonials {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

.pricing {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;

}
```

max-width and flex-basis

Comment: Can you show visually somehow what you are expecting?

Comment: Please refer to the text you're talking about, which container and if possible, when posting a lot of code like this, make it a Snippet or Fiddle for clearer view of the issue

Comment: class=" boxs " when you copy paste the code then run it then zoom in and you will understand what is happening

Comment: Hi Fahad - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more I can help with, please add a comment below my answer, or edit your question to clarify what else you want to know. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" (by clicking the checkmark beside the answer) to close out the question. If no answer provided helpful information, please add your own answer and select that as the best answer. *(You won't get any points for doing so, but that will close out the question.)* Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When zooming, it helps to use non-px values for padding, font-size, margins, etc etc.

The font-size was set to the page default (`16px`) and the distance between columns was `100px` -- these do not resize, so the content was overflowing the container.

See below example for how it looks using "view units" (`vw` units). View units are calculated according to the current screen size, so they scale even better than percents. They are calculated by dividing the screen into 100 wide by 100 tall, but they support partial units (e.g. `2.35vw`) so they are quite granular.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



.main-container {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

.logo-img {
    margin-right: auto;
}

.navbar > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 10px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}


.navbar > :nth-child(3){
    color: aquamarine;
    background-color: cornflowerblue; 
    border : 2px solid cornflowerblue;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}

.navbar > li > a {
    color: blanchedalmond;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
}

.navbar > li > a:hover {
    color: crimson;
}

.features {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: grid;

}

.boxs {
    list-style: none;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    grid-column-gap: 10vw;
    font-size:1.5vw;
}

.testimonials {
    background-color: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

.pricing {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100%;

}
```

```html
<main class="main-container">
        <nav class="navbar-container">
            <img src="logo.svg" class="logo-img">
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li class="select-items"><a href="#">Features</a></li>
                <li class="select-items"><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li class="select-items"><a href="#">Pricing Table</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <section class="features">
            <h1>The Benefits</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                 Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid</p>
            <ul class="boxs">
                <li>
                    <h2>GPS Tracking</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Heartbeat Analysis</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Security first</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Innovative idea</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Save your bills</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2>Proven technology</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                    Illum temporibus minima et ab aliquid, enim veniam. Explicabo 
                    eius non ea magni itaque aspernatur distinctio voluptatem minima,
                    est, dolorem consectetur! Dolorem?</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <section class="testimonials"></section>
        <section class="pricing"></section>
    </main>
```

Reference:

https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/